# When deploying containerimage with bar file got the error

Tags: permissions, containers, openshift, coreos, ibm-app-connect

I use IBM App Connect as Installed Operator on OpenShift v4.10 and need to install ifix. I got the ifix in tar.gz format and created Image that contains fix, pushed it to the local registry and when tried to deploy new image using yaml file(change the image name and sha algorithm) in that yaml file, i got the following error:

```
BIP8084E: Unable to create directory '/home/aceuser/ace-server', return code 13.

The specified directory could not be created. Ensure that the characters are valid, that you have the required permissions and that the parent directory exists.

Correct and reissue the command
```

Also my Dockerfile looks like this:

```
ARG FROMIMAGE=cp.icr.io/cp/appc/ace:12.0.6.0-r1
ARG IFIX
FROM ${FROMIMAGE}

USER root

RUN     mkdir -p /tmp/ifix

COPY    ./*.gz /tmp/ifix

RUN     cd /tmp/ifix \
        && microdnf install -y tar \
        && tar -xvf /tmp/ifix/*.gz \
        && ./mqsifixinst.sh /opt/ibm/ace-12 install

RUN     mkdir -p /home/aceuser/ace-server \
        && chown -R 1000:0 /home/aceuser

USER 1000
```

Command that I executing file is:

```
podman build -t aceappmb --build-arg FROMIMAGE=cp.icr.io/cp/appc/ace:12.0.6.0-r1 --file Dockerfile .
```

The USER at the end of the file was not always like this, sometimes I put over 1024 sometimes below to try as many things as possible.

Any help would be good.